# Custom T shape in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, pgf-core

I would to define a new "T" shape (i.e. the red and green shapes in the following image) so that I can then draw with TikZ the diagram below.

[image: component]

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to do. To be honest, I have read the section "Declaring New Shapes" from the PGF manual and I am completely lost with the low level pgf commands.

How could I do? Suggestions on any direction are welcomed.

Comment: Easier reading might be [makeshape](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeshape).

Comment: Can you use an `-|` arrow, e.g. `\draw [-|] (0,0) -- +(0,1);`?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Cool I didn't know that. Cannot access it now either but still cool :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT, I tried but it seems that I don't get a T shape as expected.

Comment: What do you get? How much of a T it is depends on the length of the line I guess.

Comment: I got a straight line. However, the custom shape works perfectly. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I have succeeded to create a "T" shape by adapting existing examples on the Web. Below is the pgf code to define the shape.

```
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{t}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
    \backgroundpath{
        % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
       \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
       \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
       \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@xb-\pgf@xa)/2}
       \pgf@xc=\pgf@xa
       \advance\pgf@xc by \pgfmathresult pt
       \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
       \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
       \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
       \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
       \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@ya}}
   }
}
\makeatother
```